# Does Ukraine still stamp EU passports at Boryspil airport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, passport-stamps, ukraine, kyiv

While transiting Boryspil airport yesterday, I was told by a (junior) border guard that they've stopped stamping EU passports altogether.

He told me that the "UA - EU citizens" booths often are not equipped with stamps (if it was only for Ukrainians, it would make sense, but it's for Ukrainians and EU citizens).

[image: 1]]

Does anyone have recent experience of this being the case?

I am aware that you can ask them not to stamp the passport if having filled out an optional migration card at home, which is then stamped instead. I was told, however, that you don't even have to fill it out as an EU citizen, and you will still not get a stamp by default

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I travel though Boryspil quite a lot, sometimes I get a stamp, sometimes they ask if I need a stamp and I say no. Once or twice they seem to have forgotten to put a stamp. So seems a bit hit and miss.

Answer (score 4):

I have not recently travelled to Ukraine so I cannot provide relevant personal experience, but there seems to be no formal policy of not stamping. The [Border Service](http://dpsu.gov.ua/ua/Dokumenti-dlya-peretinannya-derzhavnogo-kordonu-Ukraini/) of the country still mentions an entry mark in the passport of foreign travellers.

> Реєстрація в пункті пропуску через державний кордон включає проставлення в паспортному документі та/або імміграційній картці іноземця та особи без громадянства або в інших документах, передбачених законодавством, відмітки “В’їзд”, внесення відомостей про іноземця та особу без громадянства, їх паспортних даних до відповідного реєстру.

The [official translation](http://dpsu.gov.ua/en/border-crossing-by-foreigners-and-stateless-persons) of that is:

> The registration at the check point includes putting a mark «Entry» to the passport, immigration card or other document of a foreigner or stateless person  stipulated by a current legislation, and his passport datas are put into a special register.

So according to this official source, foreign passports should be marked upon entering the country. If the border guards decided to mostly abandon this practice for EU citizens, it is not particularly strange.

Comment: I disagree: it *would* be pretty strange seeing as they don't even accept EU ID cards for entry (although it is OK for transit - you do pass a proper passport control desk when transiting). A bunch of countries such as the CEFTA states and Georgia, who accept EU IDs, still stamp EU passports

Comment: EU ID cards are not accepted outside of the EU generally though. If there's a physically separate lane for EU citzens at Boryspil, there is nothing strange about not stamping - Ukraine currently has good relations with the EU and is not worried about EU citizens becoming illegal immigrants. You would definitely get a stamp if crossing by train for instance.

Answer (score -1):

I just traveled to Ukraine in June 2017 and, in my experience, Immigration does still stamp passports.